# Google BigQuery select sum of all the nested fields in a record

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have my schema similar to the below

```
|- name
+- cars
|  |- tesla integer
|  |- ferrari integer
```

Let's say every record specifies an order for cars and every order specifies the number of different cars that were ordered.

Now I want to query the table such that I get the sum of all the different car types.
So I want something like `SELECT SUM(cars.*) from table_name`, because I don't know what all possible nested fields the cars might have.

The schema gets dynamically generated every time a new car model is added, and thus in my query I can't possibly specify all the field names because I won't be having them.

example data -

```
name    | cars.tesla | cars.ferrari
vendor1 |     12     |      10
vendor1 |     5      |      5
vendor2 |     4      |      3
```

desired output for vendor1 -

```
name    | total_tesla | total_ferrari 
vendor1 |     17      |     15
```

So, I want to select sum of all the fields that are nested under the particular record. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT name, SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) total
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '$.cars'), r'^{|}$', ''))) kv
GROUP BY name
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' name, STRUCT<tesla INT64, ferrari INT64>(1, 2) cars UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', STRUCT(3,4)
)
SELECT name, SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) total
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '$.cars'), r'^{|}$', ''))) kv
GROUP BY name
```

result is

```sql
name    total    
a       3    
b       7
```

Below is simplified / refactored version of above:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT name, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(cars), r'^{|}$', ''))) kv
  ) total
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

And finally "final" version:

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SUM_NESTED(root STRING) AS (
  (SELECT SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) 
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(root, r'^{|}$', ''))) kv)
);

SELECT name, SUM_NESTED(TO_JSON_STRING(cars)) total
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> Update to address edited question

Below should give you direction - it gives you flatten result (`you should search this site then for how to pivot it - there are plenty of questions/answers on that topic here`)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'vendor1' name, STRUCT<tesla INT64, ferrari INT64>(12, 10) cars UNION ALL
  SELECT 'vendor1', STRUCT(5, 5) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'vendor2', STRUCT(4,3) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'vendor2', STRUCT(1,NULL)
)
SELECT 
  name, 
  REPLACE(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"', '') car, 
  SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) total
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(cars), r'^{|}$', ''))) kv
GROUP BY name, car
-- ORDER BY name, car
```

result is

```sql
name        car         total    
vendor1     ferrari     15   
vendor1     tesla       17   
vendor2     ferrari     3    
vendor2     tesla       5
```

Comment: I am trying to run this but having issues with the `null` values which I have in the columns, it fails to cast them.

Comment: try SAFE_CAST instead of CAST and let us know result. I adjusted answer with SAFE_CAST

Comment: It worked with `SAFE_CAST`. But didn't give the result I was expecting, instead this will sum up all the cars (not sum of individual car type) for a name, rather I wanted individual sum of all the car types.

Comment: Update your question so it is clear what exactly result you expect (example of input and output helps in many cases). Also, even though you saying it is not what you expected- but that is exactly what was said in your original question. So if you just changed your mind - I would recommend asking new question :o)

Comment: I apologize for lack of clarity in the question, I have edited it and added the desired output. My expectations were same from the beginning though